# What is one of the more efficient ways to search for a string in an array and get its index?

Tags: vb.net, arrays

Given an enum similar to this:

```
Friend Enum TestValue As Int32
    tstNotSet = -1
    tstA = 0
    tstB = 1
    tstC = 2
    tstD = 3
    tstE = 4
    tstF = 5
    tstG = 6
    tstH = 7
    tstI = 8
    tstJ = 9
    tstK = 10
    tstL = 11
    tstM = 12
End Enum
```

And an Array similar to this:

```
Dim TestValues() As String = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", 
                              "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M"}
```

And a string is fed in as input in some form similar to (assume it is already stored to a variable):

```
Dim tmpInput As String = "ADFGHJLM"
```

And a Sub/Method in another arbitrary class that takes in as input an array of one of more of the Enums from `TestValue`, based on the input string `tmpInput`.  Basically, I want to walk the `tmpInput` variable, and for each character, map out its equivalent member in the Enum, so that I can pass it to this Sub in the other object.  The string array `TestValues` and the Enum `TestValue` (yes, the names could be done better, but don't let that bother you too much) are laid out to match each other explicitly.

So I basically want to search the array for the matching letter, and use its index offset to know which Enum I want to map to that letter.  My current code uses a large Select Case statement, but that's just ugly (although, performance tests show it to be rather speedy, even in the debug build).

The purpose of this test case is to provide an example of a mechanism I use in a project I'm working on.  In this project, objects have a ReadOnly property that returns a string of letters composed from `TestValues`.  It also has a Sub that accepts an array of one or more Enums from `TestValue` that sets a private member in the object that is used by the aforementioned ReadOnly property.  The purpose was to store an array of smaller integer values (the Enums) rather than an array of strings for the object's internal functionality.  So I had to create a way to map back and forth between the string array and the enum.

Yes, it's easily doable with the many different collections available in .NET, but I feel those are too heavyweight for my needs, as many of my objects have enums as small as two values, hence, arrays.  I borrowed the trick from a similar example used in C to be able to select a string from a const array based on an index offset.

Anyways, as I've discovered, searching arrays in VB.NET is not trivial.  There is apparently no simple command like `TestValues.GetIndex(tmp(i))`, where `tmp(i)` is a variable holding a single character (String, not Char), that would return say, '8' if `tmp(i)` was set to 'I'.  Instead, methods like Array.FindIndex require using delegates/predicates, something I haven't fully wrapped my head around just yet (they seem like function pointers from C).

So what's the best way, other than constantly looping over the array for every input character, to locate the index offset based on the stored value?  Is the method I highlight sane or insane (hint: it's a hold-over from VBA code)?  Is there a more efficient way?

Oh, and yes, the ReadOnly property does check that the internal members are NOT set to `tstNotSet` before attempting to read from the TestValues array.  That's why that Enum member exists.

Thanks!

---

EDIT: Hopefully this doesn't muddle the explanation up *too* much, but here's an example, as simplified as I can get it, of how the look up **currently** operates using the array, enum, and input string as defined above:

```
    Dim n As Int32 = 0
    Dim Foobar(0 to 12) As TestValue

    For Each s As String In tmpInput
        Select Case Char.ToUpper(CChar(s))
            Case CChar(TestValues(tstA))
                Foobar(n) = tstA
                n += 1

            Case CChar(TestValues(tstB))
                Foobar(n) = tstB
                n += 1

            Case CChar(TestValues(tstC))
                Foobar(n) = tstC
                n += 1

            Case CChar(TestValues(tstD))
                Foobar(n) = tstD
                n += 1

            Case CChar(TestValues(tstE))
                Foobar(n) = tstE
                n += 1

            Case CChar(TestValues(tstF))
                Foobar(n) = tstF
                n += 1

            Case CChar(TestValues(tstG))
                Foobar(n) = tstG
                n += 1

            Case CChar(TestValues(tstH))
                Foobar(n) = tstH
                n += 1

            Case CChar(TestValues(tstI))
                Foobar(n) = tstI
                n += 1

            Case CChar(TestValues(tstJ))
                Foobar(n) = tstJ
                n += 1

            Case CChar(TestValues(tstK))
                Foobar(n) = tstK
                n += 1

            Case CChar(TestValues(tstL))
                Foobar(n) = tstL
                n += 1

            Case CChar(TestValues(tstM))
                Foobar(n) = tstM
                n += 1
        End Select
    Next
```

As noted in my comment to Jon Skeet, this construct, along with the rest of the Object's components, executes 100,000 times in a profiling loop in ~570ms (rough average of 3-5 runs).

Exchanging the above construct out with a smaller `Array.IndexOf` construct loops 100,000 times in ~630ms (again, 3-5 runs, rough average, the whole Object).  The new construct looks like this:

```
Dim p As Int32

p = Array.IndexOf(TestValues, s)
If p <> tstNotSet Then
    Foobar(n) = DirectCast(p, TestValue)
    n += 1
End If
```

Comment: FYI, ignore the `n` variable.  It's a supplemental counter since I'm using a `For Each` loop instead of a traditional `For` loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid I found your question extremely hard to understand, but is [`Array.IndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eha9t187.aspx) what you're looking for?

```
Dim index = Array.IndexOf(TestValues, tmp(i))
```

Comment: And I tried my best at trying to write a comprehensible test case...  Guess I have to brush up better.  What did you find the most difficult to understand?

Comment: @Kumba: For one thing, where the enum came in - and why you were making it so complicated to describe. If you just need to get from an array of strings and a "search" string to an index, why would that need more than a few sentences to describe?

Comment: @Jon: Bad habit of mine.  I tend to be extremely verbose, and will tell you the entire back-history of the Planet Druidia rather than simply state that the Princess was just captured by Spaceball 1.  I also wrote this at ~3am in the morning, so I might have not be at my most cognizant at the time.

Comment: I just tested Array.IndexOf, and it works (and is much smaller code), but it's definitely slower.  I tested my object out in a loop 100,000 times, and that executes in ~630ms, while using a large Select Case setup executes in ~570ms.

Comment: @Kumba: Yes, Select/Case will be very efficient, but you have to know all the possibilities at compile time. If efficient lookup is absolutely crucial, you could build a dictionary - although for a small number of strings, that won't actually help much. Dictionaries are mainly good for *large* lookups. Now, the question is: do you really *need* it to be any faster than 630ms for 100,000 iterations?

Comment: @Jon: I just added the lookup code I'm currently using.  And yes, I will know all the possible values at compile time.  As for need, I haven't done real-world tests yet, as the whole project is still somewhat of an infant.  I have 80+ of these objects (all similar, but they do slightly different things, yet are bound by a common interface contract), so a lot of time has been spent trying to fine tune each object, and making sure they all match up in coding style with each other.  Managing 80+ objects is not easy for just one person :)

Comment: I've tried a few other things, but the `Select Case`, while large, wins out every time.  Must be a good example of loop unrolling in action, as most of the other attempts involved a loop (and the `Select Case` is already in a loop).  Chalk down another lesson learned.

Answer (score 2):

I've got trouble tying a rope to this question.  But in any kind of lookup scenario, you *always* want to use a Dictionary.  You'll get O(1) time instead of O(n).  Something like this:

```
    Dim lookup As New Dictionary(Of Char, TestValue)
    lookup.Add("A"c, TestValue.tstA)
    lookup.Add("B"c, TestValue.tstB)
    '' etc
```

You can make the initialization cleaner in many ways.  Then:

```
    Dim value As TestValue = lookup(letter)
```

Comment: How might this be affected if the TestValues array is an array of strings?  Say `{"One", "Two", "Three"}`?  What's the initialization cost of a Dictionary?

Comment: It makes no difference, Dictionary handles strings just as well.  Initializing it takes less than a microsecond.

Comment: I'll keep a Dictionary in mind for the cases (which I have yet to implement) where I'll need to do similar at runtime instead of knowing all of the values at compile time.  In an earlier question I asked in a similar scope, someone also recommended a `HybridDictory` if I think there's a chance of my list getting to be too large.

Comment: HybridDictionary is an antique .NET 1.0 class.  No point in messing which obsolete stuff, Dictionary(Of K, V) kicks butt.

Answer (score 1):

i would say the solution by @Hans Passant is the way to go with this, but since you are dealing with chars, and chars are numbers,there is an alternative where you dont need a Dictionary.

you could store all the TestValue enum values in an array, and do something like `testValueResult = testValueArray(charCode - 65)`,i.e. just map 'A' to index 0,'B' to 1..., or even just a direct cast from the numeric form of the TestValue to its Enum since you do define it as an integer, and include a simple bounds check for tstNotSet too.

Comment: I'm not always dealing with Chars in my arrays in my project.  In fact, just two objects out of ~80 use constructs similar to my example.  The rest use full strings in the arrays instead, relying on the Enum value to point to which array offset is actually desired.

Comment: use @Hans Passants solution in those cases